# Linq performance poor

Tags: performance, linq, predicate

In a for loop I run the following code:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>> avrPrefMinute = d_averagesPerMinute.Where(n => n.Key == minuteAverage.Key.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, i, 0)));
```

This loop will always run 20 times, but when I inspect the application with VS2012 Analyser it tells me, it performs poor.

[image]

Can someone tell me how to refactor this with a more fast solution. I've read about predicates, but I'm not able to get them right.

Comment: Performs poor? How poor? Is it really a problem? What is in `d_averagesPerMinute`? How many items are you looking up? It runs 20 times, how long does that take? How often is the 20-times loop run? Do you really need it to get faster? So many questions, not enough information!

Comment: Show the loop. What is `minuteAverage`? Since `minuteAverage.Key.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, i, 0))` is always the same you could use a variable. Note that a LINQ query is nothing else than another loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks to me like `minuteAverage.Key.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, i, 0))` doesn't depend on anything within the loop. So extract that:

```
var target = minuteAverage.Key.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, i, 0));
var avrPrefMinute = d_averagesPerMinute.Where(n => n.Key == target);
```

Of course, if `d_averagesPerMinute` is a `Dictionary<DateTime, double>` you can just do a lookup instead:

```
var target = minuteAverage.Key.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, i, 0));
double result;
if (d_averagesPerMinute.TryGetValue(target, out result))
{
    // Use result
}
else
{
    // No result found
}
```

Also, I'd actually suggest that rather than

```
minuteAverage.Key.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, i, 0))
```

you use

```
minuteAverage.Key.AddMinutes(-i);
```

That's clearer, in my view.

Comment: Dammit Skeet! Coming in here, giving a better answer than me! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you perform the Subtraction in a variable prior to the where. This way you are performing that action only once, rather than on each where evaluation:

```
var key = minuteAverage.Key.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, i, 0));
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>> avrPrefMinute = d_averagesPerMinute.Where(n => n.Key == key);
```

However, this is purely based on the details you provided. Without seeing the whole loop that this is part of, and details on exactly what performance you are seeing, it is difficult to give complete advice.